# Open browser in Android

Tags: java, android, browser

I would know some information about Android browsers.

Is it possible start an intent in Android and close it when the page is loaded ? (automatically)

Is it possible to start a browser in Android (using an intent) with enabled or disabled cache ?

If yes how I can do this ?

Comment: Do you want any particular browser or webview would suffice?

Comment: Yes you can open web browser in your application using WebView

Comment: @crashOveride Depends on the complexity , what do you propose

Comment: @Alessia if you want to start a browser using with intent then, you can just open third party application there is no control on your hand, you neither clear cache nor close it when you done.

Comment: @Alessia you must have to use Webview client and for clearing cache you need to write googleCromeClient if you are interested then i will post an ans for same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Webviews in Android. 
Here is an awesome webview [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

You can listen to page loading finished event.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: And for disable / enable cache after the loading ?

Comment: mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);